# Null allowed for JSON attribute of type object?

Tags: json, jsonschema

If I have a JSON schema which defines an optional property of type `object` is it allowed to have `null` as a value? Would `null` be logically equivalent to the empty object `{}`? I would like to understand if a consumer should expect to get and be able to handle a `null` value in such cases...

I also saw the following schema but now I'm confused what's best practice:

```
{   
  "type": ["object", "null"],   
  ... 
}
```

So I guess my question comes down to is it required to have the `"null"` in the type definition above or would just `object` already allow to have `null` as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON value `null` is a value into its own.  If you want to accept such a value, you'll need to include it in `type` as you have shown.